# Bluecove Close connection issue

Tags: java, bluetooth, connection, bluecove

I use Bluecove 2.1.1 and trying to restart bluetooth service, but after closing connection and reopening I can't connect to service, I got "Connection refused" exception. I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/bluecove/issues/detail?id=90) issue on Bluecove site? I also try to change service name(also UUID) after closing connection, but it's not help. Does anyone know workaround for it? I'm simply need to restart bluetooth service.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question in the way it meant to be.

I assume that you are opening a `Connector` and let a [`SessionNotifier`](http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/obex/SessionNotifier.html) handle OBEX connections with `accecptAndOpen(ServerRequestHandler)`.
When a clients connects to your bluetooth service the specific methods in your [`ServerRequestHandler`](http://bluecove.org/bluecove/apidocs/javax/obex/ServerRequestHandler.html) are called (`onGet`, `onPut`, ..). When the client disconnects `onDisconnect` is triggered. Now you need to `acceptAndOpen` your service again to handle future connections.

Comment: I tried do in such way, but there are bug on Bluecove :) I already found solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16372206/bluecove-restart-bluetooth-stack-programmically and already defended my thesis, but anyway, thanks for replay. :)